# Get a result page from a research in google -> to PDF

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

Here is what I'm trying to do: through a python script, I would like to get the first 5 pages of results of a Google search and save them as PDF files in a folder.

What do you suggest ?

(1) I start by parsing the HTML pages one by one and then find a tool to convert them into PDF ?

(2) I find a way to direclty do all the step in one through a mod which I don't know yet ?

Thank you very much in advance for your insights !

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard Python library to download the file(s). Then you can use http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/ to convert the pages to PDF.

Note: Most web pages uses a lot of JavaScript to do all kinds of magic. So for many pages, only a full-blown web browser will get you nice/useful results. If you run into this problem, then there is no pure Python solution. [Try phantomjs as explained here](https://coderwall.com/p/5vmo1g):

```
phantomjs rasterize.js 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jakarta&printable=yes' jakarta.pdf
```

PS: I found these solutions by googling for `python convert html to pdf` You should try it once in a while.

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply. Of course I used these kind of keyword to search google before coming here. I don't think the google result page has a lot of Java in it so I will try with xhtml2pdf !

Comment: You really just want to archive the first 5 pages of Google search results (i.e. not the pages *behind* the first search results)? I think xhtml2pdf might be enough, then. Note: Google has strict rules for accessing search results with robots. You should read them or you might get banned: https://developers.google.com/web-search/terms